# errors in doing work with feedparser python

Tags: python

i am using python 3.3.3 and by using easy_install tool name setuptools-7.0. from this tool i downloaded "feedparser" but i dont understand why this is happening. when i write in cmd prompt: import parser , it gave me this errors:

```
>>> import feedparser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\feedparser-5.1.3-py3.3.egg\feedparser.py",
 line 283, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\BeautifulSoup.py", line 473
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.
__name__, attr)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now what is this , i searched from google but coud not found any pleasing solution. Any idea?

Comment: have you installed it using any guidelines or just copied and pasted the module somewhere? You have to install it using the install/setup.py file that usually comes with a 3rd party package.

Comment: aah, any suggestion to make compatible with python 3.3.3, bcz i am doing project i cannot shift to this platform

Comment: @ hagubear: i used cmd way to install them.

Comment: Beautiful Soap is working correctly. I used cmd method and it gave me +ve result

Comment: Well Python thinks there's a syntax error on line 473 on your BeautifulSoup.py file. If that's "working correctly" I guess you don't need any help after all.

Comment: feedparser is not working but beautifulsoap is working, i am unable to understand....